# How do i render a tween to a sequence of png files with Konva JS on Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, konvajs

As an experiment I want to animate a square with the Tween class and save all the frames as png files, however a proper callback such as `onUpdate` doesn't seem to exist. I would like to call it on every new frame and generate a png of the current state with a function I have already created or via another solution.

The code below is based on an example I found in [this repository on Github](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/blob/master/resources/nodejs-demo.js).

```
let i = 0;

let tween = new Konva.Tween({
  node: rect,
  duration: 1,
  x: 140,
  y: 90,
  rotation: Math.PI * 2,
  opacity: 1,
  strokeWidth: 6,
  scaleX: 1.5,
  onUpdate: () => { // does not exist
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    render_frame(i);
  },
  onFinish: () => {
    console.log("finished");
  }
});

tween.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onUpdate` callback, but we can use the `draw` event of layer to save the image:

```
let tween = new Konva.Tween({
  node: circle,
  duration: 1,
  x: 140,
  y: 90,
  rotation: Math.PI * 2,
  opacity: 1,
  strokeWidth: 6,
  scaleX: 1.5,
  onFinish: () => {
    // remove draw event
    console.log('finish');
    layer.off('.tween');
  }
});

tween.play();

layer.on('draw.tween', () => {
  // save layer to image
  console.log('to image')
})
```

https://jsbin.com/regiduzusi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

**Update:**

If you need synchronous updates you can change tween time manually.

```
const duration = 1;
const tween = new Konva.Tween({
  node: circle,
  duration: duration,
  x: 140,
  y: 90,
  rotation: Math.PI * 2,
  opacity: 1,
  strokeWidth: 6,
  scaleX: 1.5
});

const FPS = 25;
const tics = FPS * duration;


for (let i = 0; i < tics; i++) {
  tween.seek(i / tics);
  layer.draw();
  console.log('to image')
}
```

Demo 2: https://jsbin.com/fudanozani/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Your example works perfectly, except for one problem. I think that it runs in real time und skips frames, because saving images takes time. In the end I would like to have all frames at 25fps in a video. So far i worked out a solution using Konva.Animation. Is this the only way?

Comment: @JulianWeimer updated the answer. Probably it will work for you.